# Почему у меня Не работает код JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть html-страница с кнопкой и полем для ввода текста. Нужно, чтобы, когда значение в поле ввода текста изменится на "Hello", появилось всплывающее сообщение *"И тебе привет"*. Код для этого есть, но не работает.

Содержимое html-файла:

```
<body>
    <button name="mainButton" onclick="onClickButton(this)">Нажми на меня</button>

    <input oninput="onInput(this)">

    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Содержимое js-файла:

```
let counter = 0;

function onClickButton(el) {
    counter++;
    el.innerHTML = "Вы нажали на кнопку: " + counter;
}

function onInput(el) {
    if(el=="Hello")
    alert("И тебе привет")
   console.log(el.value);
}
```

Код можно запустить тут: https://codepen.io/Bay336/pen/xxmZwbB

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: потому что он с ошибками

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы хотели, чтобы, когда значение в поле ввода текста изменится на "Hello", всплыло сообщение "И тебе привет!"? Если так, то у Вас ошибка в условии: if(el=="Hello") нужно заменить на if(el.value=="Hello"). Тогда всё заработает.

Comment: @YuryPlinto отредактировать вопрос и добавить код в code block — это хорошая инициатива, но не надо его менять на исправленный в вопросе.

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо, я и не заметил, что скопировал уже исправленный мной код.

Comment: большое спасибо..... Получилось!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в теле функции `onInput` в условии: `if(el=="Hello")` нужно заменить на `if(el.value=="Hello")`. Тогда всё заработает.